# How to set the cell color to a user defined value using NPOI from F#?

Tags: excel, f#, npoi

As far as I can tell (from F# at least), cell can only be colored using predefined `NPOI.SS.UserModel.IndexedColors`. From the available methods / properties,

```
val it: ICellStyle =
  NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFCellStyle
    { ...
     FillBackgroundColor = -494s;
     FillBackgroundColorColor = NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFColor;
     FillBackgroundXSSFColor = NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFColor;
     FillForegroundColor = 64s;
     FillForegroundColorColor = null;
     FillForegroundXSSFColor = null;
     FillPattern = NoFill;
    ...
```

only `FillBackgroundColor`, `FillForegroundColor`, and `FillPattern` can be set to an `int16` value, which corresponds to the `IndexedColors` values, and the rest of the patterns are immutable. I can create a custom

```
new NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFColor([|255uy; 192uy; 150uy|])
```

color, but I simply couldn't figure out yet how to assign this either to an existing cell style or to a brand new one. All the articles I could find also only use `IndexedColors` (e.g., [1](https://www.baeldung.com/apache-poi-background-color), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58475635/1498178), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37052352/how-to-change-cell-color-with-npoi), ).

Am I missing something obvious or this is indeed not possible?

<sup>The meaning of the terms "foreground" and "background" in this context is also misleading, but that is inherited from Apache POI, and it is well documented online (again, [here](https://www.baeldung.com/apache-poi-background-color) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58475635/1498178), for example).</sup>

---

**edit**: Found two other solutions for C# ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55514395/is-there-any-way-to-add-color-to-cell-from-hex-value-like-72fe9c-in-my-excel) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65245153/npoi-set-cell-color-to-a-custom-color)), that do the obvious by setting `FillBackgroundColor` to with a custom `XSSFColor`, but, again, I couldn't figure out how to do this in F#:

```
> cs;;
val it: ICellStyle =
  NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFCellStyle
    {Alignment = General;
     BorderBottom = Thin;
     BorderDiagonal = None;
     BorderDiagonalColor = 8s;
     BorderDiagonalLineStyle = None;
     BorderLeft = Thin;
     BorderRight = Thin;
     BorderTop = Thin;
     BottomBorderColor = 64s;
     BottomBorderXSSFColor = NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFColor;
     DataFormat = 0s;
     DiagonalBorderXSSFColor = null;
     FillBackgroundColor = -494s;
     FillBackgroundColorColor = NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFColor;
     FillBackgroundXSSFColor = NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFColor;
     FillForegroundColor = 0s;
     FillForegroundColorColor = NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFColor;
     FillForegroundXSSFColor = NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFColor;
     FillPattern = NoFill;
     FontIndex = 3s;
     Indention = 0s;
     Index = 43s;
     IsHidden = false;
     IsLocked = false;
     LeftBorderColor = 64s;
     LeftBorderXSSFColor = NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFColor;
     RightBorderColor = 64s;
     RightBorderXSSFColor = NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFColor;
     Rotation = 0s;
     ShrinkToFit = false;
     TopBorderColor = 64s;
     TopBorderXSSFColor = NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFColor;
     VerticalAlignment = Bottom;
     WrapText = false;}

> c;;
val it: XSSFColor =
  NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFColor {ARGB = [|255uy; 255uy; 192uy; 150uy|];
                                 ARGBHex = "FFFFC096";
                                 HasAlpha = false;
                                 HasTint = false;
                                 Index = 0s;
                                 Indexed = 0s;
                                 IsAuto = false;
                                 IsIndexed = false;
                                 IsRGB = true;
                                 IsThemed = false;
                                 RGB = [|255uy; 192uy; 150uy|];
                                 RGBWithTint = [|255uy; 192uy; 150uy|];
                                 Theme = 0;
                                 Tint = 0.0;}

> cs.FillBackgroundColor;;   
val it: int16 = -494s

> cs.FillBackgroundColor <- c;;

  cs.FillBackgroundColor <- c;;
  --------------------------^

/Users/toraritte/dev/clones/dotNET/slate-excel-reports/stdin(332,27): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    'int16'    
but here has type
    'XSSFColor'    

> cs.FillBackgroundColorColor;;
val it: IColor = NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFColor {ARGB = null;
                                                ARGBHex = null;
                                                HasAlpha = false;
                                                HasTint = false;
                                                Index = -494s;
                                                Indexed = -494s;
                                                IsAuto = false;
                                                IsIndexed = true;
                                                IsRGB = false;
                                                IsThemed = false;
                                                RGB = null;
                                                RGBWithTint = null;
                                                Theme = 0;
                                                Tint = 0.0;}

> cs.FillBackgroundColorColor <- c;;

  cs.FillBackgroundColorColor <- c;;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/Users/toraritte/dev/clones/dotNET/slate-excel-reports/stdin(334,1): error FS0810: Property 'FillBackgroundColorColor' cannot be set
```

Comment: Please don't flag this as duplicate of C# solutions as those solutions clearly don't work the same way and this question is tagged only for F#. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I failed to notice that a cell's `CellStyle` property returns the generic `ICellStyle`, which has to be cast down to `NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFCellStyle` in order to gain access to the `FillBackgroundXSSFColor` and `FillForegroundXSSFColor` properties.

Also, here's a summary of which property does what, quoting from this answer:

> As said in my linked answer: Cell interior uses pattern fills. The fill background color is the color **behind** the pattern.The fill **foreground** color is the color of the pattern. To fill the cell using a plain color, you need using fill **foreground** color `CellStyle.setFillForegroundColor` and solid pattern `FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND`.

In my case, I need `NPOI.SS.UserModel.FillPattern` and `FillForegroundXSSFColor` then. The full code:

```
let setCellColor (cell: ICell) (rgb: byte array) =
    let xssfCell = cell :?> NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFCell
    let newCellStyle: NPOI.SS.UserModel.ICellStyle = xssfCell.Sheet.Workbook.CreateCellStyle()
    match xssfCell.CellStyle with
    | :? NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFCellStyle as xssfCellStyle ->
        let color = new NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFColor(rgb)
        xssfCellStyle.FillForegroundXSSFColor <- color
        xssfCellStyle.FillPattern <- NPOI.SS.UserModel.FillPattern.SolidForeground
    | _ -> failwith "'newCellStyle' cannot be cast to XSSFCellStyle"
    xssfCell.CellStyle <- newCellStyle
```

To call with RGB colors:

```
let getCell (workbook: NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFWorkbook) (sheetNumber: int) (address: string) =
    let sheet: ISheet = workbook.GetSheetAt(sheetNumber)
    let cellAddress = new CellAddress (address)
    getCellByAddress sheet cellAddress

let rgb: byte array = [|255uy; 192uy; 150uy|]

setCellColor (getCell o 3 "a7") rgb;;
```

To call with hex color string:

```
let hexStringToRGB (hexString: string) =
    let isHexColor (color: string) =
        "^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})$"
        |> fun regexPattern -> new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(regexPattern)
        |> fun regex -> regex.IsMatch(color)
    match (isHexColor hexString) with
    | false ->
        failwith "Invalid hex color string."
    | true ->
        let hexString = hexString.TrimStart('#')
        let r = System.Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(0, 2), 16)
        let g = System.Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(2, 2), 16)
        let b = System.Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(4, 2), 16)
        [|r; g; b|]

setCellColor (getCell o 3 "a7") (hexStringToRGB "#ffc096");;
```

> NOTE: `setCellColor` replaces the input cell's style with a new one, so one has to take care of re-creating the previous style options if they are needed.
> When I modified `setCellColor` to modify the cell's own style object instead of replacing it, the result was that the entire worksheet got painted to the color used from that specific cell going forward. Not sure where I screwed up, but beware.
>
> **update** See the solution in [How to change the color of a cell to a user defined value while keeping its existing style using NPOI from F#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77705384/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-cell-to-a-user-defined-value-while-keeping-its-exis).